# How can I implement a UICollectionView footer in RxSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, storyboard, reactive

I can't seem to find a way to add a footer view to my UICollectionView. I normally use RxSwift, I tried the non-RxSwift way, and still, the footer does not show.

What I do is I fetch my data through my ViewModel and feed it to my CollectionView in my ViewController like so:

```
viewModel.output.data.drive(self.usersCollectionView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "user", cellType: UserCollectionFooterView.self)) {[weak self] row, data, cell in
     guard let self = self else {return }
     cell.set(user: data)
}.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

I've created a `UserCollectionFooterView` class and checked the "Section Footer" in my storyboard. I added a button inside the footer view, and linked the IBOutlet to my `UserCollectionFooterView` class.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
class UserCollectionFooterView : UICollectionReusableView {
    @IBOutlet weak var leaveButton: UIButton!
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

In my ViewController, I've registered the class:

```
 usersCollectionView.register(UserCollectionFooterView, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: "UserCollectionFooterView")
```

And I've implemented these two functions:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: usersCollectionView.bounds.width, height: 100)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    return collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "UserCollectionFooterView", for: indexPath)
}
```

Moreover, my ViewController implements `UICollectionViewDelegate`.

Please, can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how can I add the footerView using RxSwift?

The optimal solution is to implement a footer for the entire collection view, but since I only have one section in my collection view, it can be a section's footer view.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting collection views layout *footerReferenceSize*.

Comment: @Jane Already implemented the collectionView delegate function to set footerReferenceSize

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).